# HTML dynamically creating sub-pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

Suppose I have a website `www.mywebsite.com` which contains rows of links. When you click on each link you are brought to `www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/1`. If these links are dynamically created (i.e. the user submits new links to www.mywebsite.com), then the these following pages must also be dynamically created.

```
www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/1
www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/2
www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/3
...
www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/n
```

How do you create these pages using HTML / Javascript?

An example would be this website:

```
http://www.postrandomonium.com/
```

If you see the first box, it contains an id of 4248

You can go to `http://www.postrandomonium.com/status/4248` to view a webpage that is SPECIFIC to the information in #4248.

Obviously, these pages are created on the fly so how can I approach this in code?

Comment: There are no subfolders or subpages - the domain gets rewritten or routed. If you are using Apache, look up [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: look at something called MVC

Comment: As kingkero said, there are no dynamically created pages. Odd are there's one page that processes the parameters you see via mod_rewrite. The normal format would be something like `http://www.postrandomonium.com/index.php?action=status&id=4248`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is url rewriting: behind the scene, the server convert the url from an human-readable shape `www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/1` to a server-readable shape `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?folder=subfolder&id=1`

You can use url rewriting with every major http server, like [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/intro.html) or [IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

If you are interested to write that kind of website with php, I suggest you to use a framework, like Slim

http://www.slimframework.com/

or Silex

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: OK, now this makes perfect sense. Why does url rewriting exist? Is it for URL cosmetic reasons? Or...does it protect the file's owner against possible misuse

Answer (score 0):

If you realy want to do something like this, see my solution:

1) Generate dynamically  links like this: [Actually there are two inputs, namely one that is submit button that looks like a link and the other one is an invisible input.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            input[class="buttonLikeLink"] {
                background:none;
                border:none; 
                padding:0;
                background-color:#FFFFF0;
                color: #0000FF;
             //   border-bottom:1px solid #444; 
                text-decoration:underline;
                cursor:pointer;
                cursor:hand;
            }

        input[class="invisible"] {
            background:none;
            border:none; 
            padding:0;
            background-color:#FFFFF0;
            color: #FFFFF0;
            cursor: default;
        }



        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form   target="_blank"  method='POST' action="generate.php">
            <input class="buttonLikeLink" type="submit" value="the name of the link">
            <input class="invisible" type="text" value="myId" name="myName">
        </form>

        <form   target="_blank"  method='POST' action="generate.php">
            <input class="buttonLikeLink" type="submit" value="the name of the link 2">
            <input class="invisible" type="text" value="myId2" name="myName">
        </form>


    </body>

</html>
```

2) generate.php just redirects this to the actual page:

```
<?php

$myId=$_POST['myName'];

// Here you can access the database if you want using a query based on $myId


?>
```

```
<h1> 

    This is a very unusual solution! 

</h1>
<p> <?php echo $myId ?> </p>
```

I hope that this solution can be useful for you. Maybe you can even improve it.

As @Anthony-Garcia called our attention below, you can do the same using normal links and Ajax.

Comment: This won't work with direct link, and you can emulate this with pure javascript and normal links.

Comment: @Anthony-Garcia. You are right - this does not work as direct link. I am not sure if he asked for a direct link. Yes, sure, he can use AJAX to access the database. Thank you for calling my attention to this important point. I just thought this could be an interesting non-usual solution.